# Why the need of a bitwise "and" for some char to byte conversions in Java?

Tags: java, c#, type-conversion, bit-manipulation

Here I'm working with a Java to C# sample app translation that involves cryptography (AES and RSA and so on...)

At some point in Java code (the one that actually works and being translated to C#), I've found this piece of code:

```
for (i = i; i < size; i++) {
    encodedArr[j] = (byte) (data[i] & 0x00FF);
    j++;
} // where data variable is a char[] and encodedArr is a byte[]
```

After some googling ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28byte%29%20%20%26%200x00FF%20Java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)), I've seen that this is a common behaviour mainly on Java code...

I know that `char` is a 16-bit type and `byte` is 8-bit only, but I couldn't understand the reason for this bitwise and operation for a `char->byte` conversion.

Could someone explain?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its probably to circumvent a possible overflow if there is some value in the upper byte of the char. Otherwise just casting it would result in an overflow for a byte since it can only hold 255 (FF) as a maximum value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you convert 0x00FF to binary it becomes `0000 0000 1111 1111`

When you and anything with 1, it is itself:

`1 && 1 = 1, 0 && 1 = 0`

When you and anything with 0, it is 0

`1 && 0 = 0, 0 && 0 = 0`

When this operation occurrs `encodedArr[j] = (byte) (data[i] & 0x00FF);` it's taking the last 8 bits and the last 8 bits only of the data and storing that. It is throwing away the first 8 bits and storing the last 8

The reason why this is needed is because a byte is defined as an eight bit value. The bitwise and exists to stop a potential overflow -> IE assigning 9 bits into a byte

A char in Java is [2 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956734/why-does-the-java-char-primitive-take-up-2-bytes-of-memory)! This logic is there to stop an overflow. However, as someone pointed out below, this is pointless because the cast does it for you. Perhaps someone was being cautious?

Comment: wouldn't you want to split the char into 2 bytes to preserve the information. and I think you meant bits

Comment: Absolutely. I did mean bits

Comment: Its not really "throwing them away", the bytes are still there, its just making the type small enough that a cast to another type won't result in an overflow. At least thats what the & is doing, the cast throws them away if you want to clarify.

Comment: The bitwise and is zeroing the first 8 bits, thus "Throwing them away"

Comment: It's completely pointless in Java, though. The high byte is already discarded by the cast.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, it is quite unnecessary, but the sort of thing people put in "just in case". According to the JLS, [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

> A narrowing conversion of a char to an integral type T likewise simply
>   discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of
>   bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the resulting value to be a negative number, even though chars
>   represent 16-bit unsigned integer values.

Similar code is often needed in widening conversions to suppress sign extension.

Comment: It works in Java without the mask/cast, but not in C#. C# is a little more strict about narrowing conversions.

Comment: @RonBeyer Maybe the code was written by someone who was thinking a bit C# although it is stated to be Java.

Comment: The code is Java but he's converting to C#, so its just an important thing to note since it can't be removed on the C# side.

Comment: @RonBeyer what's the story with C# here? In the default `unchecked` context, they use the same rule (to quote, "If the source type is larger than the destination type, then the source value is truncated by
discarding its “extra” most significant bits")

Comment: @harold yes, when you use `unchecked`, but a 1:1 conversion of the code doesn't have that. You would have to use `encodedArr[j] = unchecked((byte)(data[i]));` Edit: checking on this now, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @RonBeyer but it's the default.. all you'd have to do is not check that checkbox in the build settings that sets it to checked

Comment: @harold Yes, you seem to be right, I hadn't noticed that it was set to use unchecked by default, I always specified it when requiring an unchecked operation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a way to truncate the value by keeping only the least significat bits so it "fits" in a byte!

I hope it helps!