# Java programming Character size

Tags: java, char, size

Char size in old languages like c/c++ is 1 byte .but if you talk about in java char size becomes 2 byte.can you elaborate why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Java char primitive take up 2 bytes of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956734/why-does-the-java-char-primitive-take-up-2-bytes-of-memory)

Comment: Tip: For working with individual characters, learn to use the methods related to [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers, the number assigned by the Unicode Consortium to each of the 143,859 known characters. The `char` type is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

The `char` data type in Java originally used for representing 16-bit Unicode. Therefore the size of the char data type in Java is 2 byte

Answer (score 0):

Java uses UTF-16 encoding.
C/C++ is using UTF-8.

8 and 16 are the number of bits here.

Answer (score 0):

The evolution of Java was at the time when the Unicode standards had been defined for a very smaller character set. Java was designed for using Unicode Transformed Format (UTF)-16 when the UTF-16 was designed. The `char` data type in Java is originally used for representing 16-bit Unicode. Therefore the size of the char data type in Java is 2 byte, and same for the C language is 1 byte. Hence Java uses Unicode standard.

Answer (score 0):

Java follows the Unicode standards. Java was developed for  worldwide interchange, processing, and display of the written texts of the diverse languages and technical disciplines whereas C and C++ not . So the char size for java is 2 bytes and that for C and C++ is 1 byte.